# How to call function multiple times with different input arguments in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a function `f(df, index)`, which takes a pyspark dataframe `df` and an index as input arguments and returns a dataframe with additional columns.
I have multiple index values for which I want to run the function and store the output dataframes. Let's say `index_all = df.select('index').distinct()`.
Now I want to run the function for all values within `index_all`, so:

```
total_results = []
for index in index_all

   result = f(df, index)
   
   total_results = total_results.append(result)
```

How do I do this when using pyspark dataframes as efficient as possible?

Comment: what operations do you perform inside the function? if all operations within the function are pyspark compatible, i don't see a challenge. what issues are you facing?

Comment: @samkart inside the function all operations are indeed pyspark compatible. However, using a regular for loop is not as efficient as it could be. Do you know how to make this more efficient?

Comment: It depends on the operations in your function. Maybe you can use a f.when(idx==X). Or maybe you can filter the dataframe on each index, perform your function and Union the resulting dataframes after your function.

Comment: You can use foldLeft in pyspark. Here's an example. https://mrpowers.medium.com/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe-with-foldleft-42133f82de04

Answer (score 0):

An example solution sourced from other answers.

```
import sys
import threading
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
    ["01001", 1288770200],
    ["01002", 1278770000],
    ["01003", 1258780201],
    ["01003", 1238750044],
    ["01001", 1288770243],
    ["01001", 1278775030],
    ["01001", 1258780281],
    ["01003", 1238753044],
    ["01005", 1278770000],
    ["01006", 1258780201],
    ["01006", 1238750044],

]

df1Columns = ["index", "value"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)

columns_list = list(df1.columns)
print(columns_list)

index_list = df1.select(["index"]).distinct().rdd.map(lambda x: x["index"]).collect()
print(index_list)


def operate_on_df(df: DataFrame, given_index: int):
    count_value = df.filter(F.col("index") == given_index).count()
    return {"given_index": given_index, "count_value": count_value}


count_result_list = []

for ii in index_list:
    my_count = operate_on_df(df1, ii)
    count_result_list.append((ii, my_count))

print(count_result_list)


def task(arg_tuple):
    df = arg_tuple[0]
    ii = arg_tuple[1]
    return operate_on_df(df, ii)


def run_multiple_jobs():
    # for jj in range(40):
    #  t = threading.Thread(target=task, args=(df1, index_list[jj%2]))
    #  t.start()

    int_list = list(range(40))
    arg_list = []
    for kk in int_list:
        arg_tuple = (df1, index_list[kk%5])
        arg_list.append(arg_tuple)

    print("Argument list is as follows")
    print(arg_list)

    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        # issue tasks into the thread pool

        result = pool.map_async(task, arg_list)
        # wait for tasks to complete
        result.wait()
        # report all tasks done
        print('All tasks are done')


    return result.get()


returned_values = run_multiple_jobs()

print(returned_values)
```

Descriptive and self-explantory output :

```
['index', 'value']
['01005', '01001', '01006', '01003', '01002']
[('01005', {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}), ('01001', {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}), ('01006', {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}), ('01003', {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}), ('01002', {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1})]
Argument list is as follows
[(DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01005'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01001'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01006'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01003'), (DataFrame[index: string, value: bigint], '01002')]
All tasks are done
[{'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01005', 'count_value': 1}, {'given_index': '01001', 'count_value': 4}, {'given_index': '01006', 'count_value': 2}, {'given_index': '01003', 'count_value': 3}, {'given_index': '01002', 'count_value': 1}]
```