# PySpark running embarassingly parallel jobs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, embarrassingly-parallel

So I am trying to run 1000+ embarassingly parallel jobs using PySpark on a cluster. I instantiate 5 executors, each having 20 cores, i.e. should be able to execute 100 jobs concurrently, as far as I understand.

This is what I have so far, "values" containing tuples, each tuple being a job

```
values = [(something, something_else),..., (howdy, partner)]    
rdd_values = sc.parallelize(values)
results = rdd_values.map(my_func).collect()
```

A few questions

1. Is this really the recommended way of doing this in PySpark?
2. The Spark UI is really unhelpful when I run more jobs than I have cores available. What am I missing?
3. Why do people use PySpark? It seems so cumbersome

I know this is probably not what PySpark is best suited at but it is the tool I have available.

**Rant**

Furthermore, it's **really** frustrating that there is no way of getting a simple progressbar out of this (or is there?).
The Spark UI only helps me so far.

Comment: are you running on a cluster or locally on your computer / laptop ?

Comment: On a cluster. Otherwise this would be horribly overcomplicated. Updated question to clarify this, thanks.

Comment: Can you add the spark-submit command you are using? Also why are reading values in from a single source and collecting all the data in the driver?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You can use futures to run parallel jobs like shown here. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/spark-parallel-job-submission-38b41220397b

Comment: I am running it from within a Jupyter Notebook, so I don't have a spark-submit command. 

Each job consist of executing an .exe executable with some parameters: the "values". The output is mainly just to check whether or not these executions went ok or not. 
Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post more details about what exactly your task is in more detail? The question is very vague. Are you running this on a databricks cluster with Jupyter frontend? We can continue this discussion in chat if you want.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214474/how-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-one-sparkcontext-from-separate-threads-in-pyspark

Comment: I posted an answer similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961816/how-to-call-function-multiple-times-with-different-input-arguments-in-pyspark/77010559#77010559

Answer (score 0):

Turns out; with my expected behaviour being: "I want to run a 1000 jobs, 100 at a time" this seems to work:

```
values = [(something, something_else),..., (howdy, partner)]    
rdd_values = sc.parallelize(values, numSlices=len(values))
results = rdd_values.map(my_func).collect()
```

The difference being the added "numSlices" argument.

Thanks for your suggestions